# Is my PHP code object oriented?

Tags: php, oop

If I made my PHP code which would connect me to my MySQL database in a separate PHP file and made a require on the necessary pages of my website would the DB Connent PHP file be an Object Orentated item ?

Comment: +1 , He's a programming beginner. So be gentle!

Comment: He still a beginner ? 2.475 points.

Comment: @androidnation I asked this question 6 years ago, sorry to be the bearer of bad news

Comment: Not at all. 6 years and 2 475. As such a question, you were building a great career. Great for you sir.

Answer (score 3):

[OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is a concept. So if you include a file via the require command and this included file utilizes OOP then your script uses the concept of OOP. If not then your mainscript doesn't include it, too.

Answer (score 3):

Oliver, Check out this [link](http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/) about object oriented PHP.  It will give you a basic intro and then you can determine if indeed your code is object oriented.

Comment: which link? I don't see one :)

Comment: Just corrected it.  Check it out now. Sorry first SO answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that basically *require* only puts the text from the required file into the executing .php file.

So it doesn't make your code any more OOP by requiring another file, it just makes it more *structured* and maybe more *maintainable* in the future, but not OOP.

OOP would mean that you have created some sort of object that you call from now on to execute commands against. You can read more on [OOP in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

I strongly suggest you read the book "Code Complete" if you are just beginning with programming and just keep on experimenting. The road to OOP programming usually leads through lots of bad procedural programming (that's what you are most likely doing right now).

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the code in the seperate file. If it's within a class that you call, rather than just a set of functions, then yes. If not, no.

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean :) 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You could also use MySQLi, which is object oriented as well.